# 123-reg DNS only working with subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

I have a Domain Name with 123-reg that is using their name servers, and I have two `A` records for this Domain Name that point to my Windows VPS.

In my VPS, I then have IIS running the default site with bindings for `*` and `www`. This works for http://www.example.com. However, when trying http://example.com, it says the DNS records couldn't be found.

EDIT: The below possible duplicate isn't correct as that question has `www.example.com` pointing to a different IP that `example.com`, whereas mine isn't working at all. Trust me, I've already looked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure proper DNS records for separate web host and e-mail server](https://serverfault.com/questions/381741/configure-proper-dns-records-for-separate-web-host-and-e-mail-server)

Comment: It sounds as though your issue might indeed by DNS, and as though your question might be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/381741/configure-proper-dns-records-for-separate-web-host-and-e-mail-server. The short version is: from your description, you indeed do not seem to have an A record for `example.com`, but only for www, and for any other subdomains (i.e. the www is redundant, because it is part of *.example.com). The fix should be creating the missing DNS record for your actual domain, e.g. `example.com in A [IP]`

Comment: Yes but the problem here @iwaseatenbyagrue is that I can only add subdomain names for A records (so I can't add 'domain.co.uk' to route it to my VPS, I can only add 'www' or 'subdomain'.). I already tried the wildcard but it just sends everything apart from domain.co.uk to it

Comment: OK - can you create a CNAME for `example.com`? If so, just point it to your `www` record. If you can't do that either, then I am not sure how you can fix this: you really would need 'full' access to your DNS settings.

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue nope just tried it >:(

Comment: Your records `www` and `*` covers all subdomains but not the domain itself. If you can add DNS records in some kind of web manager or wizard, try adding `@ IN A 127.0.0.1` where `@` refers to the root of your zone i.e. `example.com.` and localhost is to be replaced with your actual IP.  Next you should add corresponding hostname to your IIS, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **skipped phases 4-5** in the 123-reg FAQ: [How do I set up my DNS for Web forwarding?](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Web-Forwarding/how-do-i-set-up-my-dns-for-web-forwarding-2526/) manual.

> 1. Login to your [123-reg control panel](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/secure/).
> 2. In the *Domain names* section, select the relevant domain name in the drop-down list and click on the *Manage* button.
> 3. Click on the *Manage DNS (A, MX, CNAME, TXT)* link.
> 4. On the *Advanced DNS* tab, click the edit button and change the IP next to the `@` type A record to `94.136.40.82`
> 5. Click on the *Save* button.
> 6. Repeat Steps 4 and 5 for the www type A record.

Of course **this works the same way** whether you use their web forwarding or **your own IP**.

As [RFC 1035,  5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5.1) defines, `@` is used to denote the current `$ORIGIN`, defined earlier in the zone file.

You don't see it in your web based configuration tool, but as you set the other hostnames without the origin, e.g. `www` instead of `www.example.com.`, it suggests `example.com.` is your `$ORIGIN` and you can refer to it with just `@ IN A`.