# DNS setup for Google mail and separate web host

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, g-suite, google

We use a Google Email solution and now want to configure a website on a different hosting provider. I have read the following [Configure proper DNS records for separate web host and e-mail server](https://serverfault.com/questions/381741/configure-proper-dns-records-for-separate-web-host-and-e-mail-server) so it seems to be possible.

However Google registered the domain at Godaddy somehow (I was not involved in the order process so don't know the details) and now I can see long list of entries on the DNS configuration page. See the link below:

[DNS parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3UYE.png)

So if the website is hosted on 1.2.3.4 then which entry should I change to what value?

Comment: "However Google registered the domain at Godaddy somehow..." I highly doubt that.

Comment: @ceejayoz before june 2014, Google refered to eNom and GoDaddy, see https://www.whoishostingthis.com/blog/2015/01/07/google-vs-godaddy/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek There's a big difference between them saying "you can buy a domain somewhere like GoDaddy" before they had their own offering and Google actually *using GoDaddy as a registrar* as stated in the post, which to my knowledge was never the case.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, I have tried to find past references but failed to do so but I do recall that they started by using other registrars.

Comment: Just for information: The complete G Suite sign up process was made by a non technical user. He never visited godaddy site directly and under his google account there is a generated godaddy username (~20 characters random string). So I suppose it was done by some Google process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the A record to point to where you want the website to be hosted. Usually the A record points to an IP address.

If you are using a load balancer like the one from AWS, you will need to use CNAME instead of an A record. Some DNS providers don't support the CNAME pointing to a non-IP address, so if that is the case you will have to move the DNS to another provider.  Cloudflare, DNS Made Easy and Amazon Route53 are all good choices when it comes to features and performance.

The email and website can be on a different hosting provider than where the DNS is hosted. It doesn't have to be on Google, or on Godaddy, even though the DNS is currently there.

Comment: The data value of a DNS A record type is an IPv4 address. Not usually, always. And the CNAME data value is a name.

Comment: "Cloudflare, DNS Made Easy and Amazon Route53 are all the best performant DNS providers," this is purely subjective or do you have hard data to back that up?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek based on what I had read; who knows maybe it changed. I'll just update it to say that they are good choices.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to remove all existing A records and only add one that points to the shared hosting servers IP. 
Besides this the CNAME value for www was set to @ and now it is woring fine.